# Remove extra padding in custom button control

Tags: c#

I need some help on removing extra padding around the edges of a custom button control in C#.

[image]

The width of this button is 68, and I'd like to keep it that way. If I change it to 70, then the text fits all on one line.

Button control code:

```
public partial class FlatButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    public FlatButton() : base()
    {
        FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(58, 58, 58);
        ForeColor = Color.White;
    }

    protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Pen pen = new Pen(FlatAppearance.BorderColor, 1);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);
    }

    public override void NotifyDefault(bool value)
    {

    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to remove the extra padding and allow the text to fit all in one line?

Comment: Look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.padding(v=vs.110).aspx) for information on how to do this.

Comment: `..ForeColor = Color.White; ..  Padding = new Padding(0);` would remove any padding. However a Button doesn't come with a default padding. So your text or your font seem to be too large.. Also, please dispose of your pen!

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the padding doesn't work. I guess I'll have to resort to setting the width of the button a bit wider.

Comment: setting the padding works fine, but not in your case, since there is none to begin with.

Comment: Right...what I need is some way to set negative padding.